# PHP - CodeIgniter Notifications

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, codeigniter, notifications

I'm currently working on a project using CodeIgniter web framework. I just have this question in mind: how do I create a notification feature? Specifically, this notification feature would cover some activities that are happening in my application. Like for example, a student requested an appointment with a guidance counselor. How do I create the notification that will be sent to the guidance counselor?

I have an idea about how the notification will be inserted in the database, but I'm not quite so sure. Another question: What if a notification comes from one user and should be sent to many users? How do I write it in the database? And, how do I have a real time notification? I mean, when a user no longer needs to refresh the page if a new notification has been sent to him or her, a notification bubble or whatever will just popout somewhere.  Of course, this needs a javascript/jquery/ajax (which I'm really not enthusiastic about haha), and I have an idea how it'll work, but then again, I'm not quite so sure. Can someone help me? I just need a brief walk-through, or something that will get me started or that will give me an idea about the things I need and the things I have to learn.

Thank you in advance for the answers.

Comment: What have you tried so far ? what kind of notification ? Browser Notification ?

Comment: I haven't really tried anything yet because I'm working on another module, amd I'm still researching for this notif feature. But my plan is, have a notification table with a notification status(not seen, or seen), and when there is a not yet seen notif, it'll be on the notification list of a user. Of course, it isn't real time, and probably inefficient, so I still need to learn more.

Answer (score 2):

You can organize your database like this:

## users

```
- user_id
- name
- etc.
```

## notifications

```
- notification_id
- content
- date
```

## users_notifications

```
- notification_id
- user_id
- view_date
```

Then you just have to play with datas.

For the ajax, you can make a route, or a controller like

## mysite/notifications_controller with actions:

- index: used to fetch notifications from current user and send it to your browser. You can output them in json. Call it with ajax. Pull
  it with a periodic call.
- mark_as_read: used to mark a notificiation as readed. You pass the id on an ajax call (when the user click on the notification or whatever).

If you want to display live notifications, I suggest you to learn NodeJS :).